# Rspec request specs: No routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Writing request specs for rail app (api-only) and running into an issue where request spec returns:

```
Failures:

  1) Api::V1::BooksController sends a list of books
     Failure/Error: get api_books_path
     
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/books"
```

At first, I though maybe test couldn't infer the directory path so I made sure that `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` was in `spec/rails_helper`

**directory structure of spec directory**:

```
spec/requests
└── api
    └── v1
        └── books_spec.rb
```

**contents of spec/requests/api/v1/books_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::BooksController, :type => :request  do

  before { host! "api.localhost.com" }

  it "sends a list of books" do

    get api_books_path

    expect(response).to be_successful
  end
end
```

**directory structure of app/controllers**:

```
app/controllers
├── api
│   └── v1
│       └── books_controller.rb
├── application_controller.rb
└── concerns
```

**Contents of `config/routes.rb`**:

```
require 'api_versions'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json}, constraints: { subdomain: ['api', 'staging.api'] }, path: "/" do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiVersions.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :books, only: [:index]
    end
  end
end
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am missing; appreciate any feedback.

Comment: what `api_books_path` in the spec returns?

Comment: @HubertJakubiak it returns "/books", which is the expected route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good night sleep really does help. I woke up; took another look at the problem and realized the culprit.

- Main issue was that in `spec/requests/api/v1/books_spec.rb` host was set to `api.localhost.com` (localhost.com; really?) when it should be `api.localhost:3000`.
- Second issue was forgetting to set the correct value for `config.action_dispatch.tld_length` in test; I did in dev but forgot to do so in test.